# Finding the $p$-roots of $e^H (L-p)(e^{p-H}-1)^2+e^L (H-p)(e^{p-L}-1)^2$ to show that it's positive over a certain range

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, exponential-function, roots

> For my research, I'm trying to prove that the following expression is positive for $p$ between $\frac{H+L}{2}$ and $H$:
>
> $$e^{H} (L-p) \left(e^{p-H}-1\right)^2+e^{L} (H-p) \left(e^{p-L}-1\right)^2 $$
>
> The assumptions are that $H>L>0$.

From messing around with parametrizations, I'm reasonably confident that the expression above has 3 roots: $p=L,H,\frac{L+H}{2}$. If I knew that to be true, it would be relatively straightforward to show that the expression must be positive for $p$ between $\frac{H+L}{2}$ and $H$ as I desire.

Can anyone see anyway to prove this? Suggestions on other routes to proving the positivity in the specified region would also be more than welcome. Thanks for any input.